# Mac CoreLocation Services does not ask for permissions

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-location

I'm writing a Mac App that needs to use CoreLocation services. The code and location works fine, as long as I manually authenticate the service inside the security preference pane. However the framework is not automatically popping up with a permission dialog. The documentation states:

> Important The user has the option of denying an application’s access
>   to the location service data. During its initial uses by an
>   application, the Core Location framework prompts the user to confirm
>   that using the location service is acceptable. If the user denies the
>   request, the CLLocationManager object reports an appropriate error to
>   its delegate during future requests.

I do get an error to my delegate, and the value of +locationServicesEnabled is correct on CLLocationManager. The only part missing is the prompt to the user about permissions. This occurs on my development MPB and a friends MBP. Neither of us can figure out whats wrong.

Has anyone run into this?

Relevant code:

```
_locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];    
[_locationManager setDelegate:self];
[_locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer];
...
[_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: Give us the full details of the error for a start

Comment: It is the generic error the CoreLocation framework gives when it's unable to locate a user. 'kCLErrorLocationUnknown'

Comment: Please can you provide the Radar ID for the bug report I will get it looked at ASAP.

Comment: Sure, sorry for the delay. The ID is: 11791451. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I found that on the Mac, that when you start location services by calling

```
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

It triggers

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
```

With a status of

```
kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined
```

If you watch for this status, then start updating the location again, it triggers the permission dialog: e.g.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
{
    switch (status) {
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
            NSLog(@"Location Services are now Authorised");
            [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

            break;

        case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
            NSLog(@"Location Services are now Denied");
            break;

        case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
            NSLog(@"Location Services are now Not Determined");

            //  We need to triger the OS to ask the user for permission.
            [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
            [_locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

            break;

        case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
            NSLog(@"Location Services are now Restricted");
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```